# Factoring an Algebra I problem

Tags: algebra-precalculus

$$x^{n+6} + x^{n+2} + x^n$$  This is a problem from my son's math class and I have no idea how to do it or to explain it.

Comment: Remember $x^{a+b} = x^a x^b$.

Comment: $ x^n(x^6+x^2+1)=?$

Answer (score 3):

I'd explain first that $x^{n+6}$ means that you multiply together $$\underbrace{x\cdot x\cdots x}_{n+6\text{ times}}$$ and that since there are $n+6$ multiplications of $x$, you can split them into $$\underbrace{x\cdot x\cdots x}_{n\text{ times}}\cdot \underbrace{x\cdot x\cdots x}_{6\text{ times}} $$

so that finally $x^{n+6} = x^n \cdot x^6$.

Then similarly $x^{n+2} = x^n\cdot x^2$, so that the entire expression can be rewritten as $$x^n\cdot x^6 + x^n\cdot x^2 + x^n\cdot 1$$

at which point you can factor out the common $x^n$ in each term, using the distributive law.

Mathematically this leaves a little to be desired, since the explanation only makes sense when $n$ is a whole number, whereas the identity $x^{n+6} = x^n\cdot x^6$ holds for all $n$, but at your son's level this probably isn't important.